# OS X Associate an extension with the application

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

In my application, I need to associate an extension with my application programmatically. That is when my application runs, it associates the extensions with itself as preferred application.

On Windows, this is done by using Registry APIs.

I am not able to find out how to achieve this in Mac OS X using Cocoa or Core Foundation in my C++ program.

This is like application associate itself with the extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  It seems a reasonable enough question to me, given the number of Windows apps that ask whether they should handle a particular extension.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want *your* app to activate when a document with the overtaken extension is double-clicked in Finder, yes? Unfortunately there is no API to "take over" an extension not already declared by the app's Info.plist and, for what should be obvious security reasons, there is no way to modify that mechanism at runtime.

The closest you can come is allowing *any* extension, which will allow your app to be launched or activated by dragging the document onto the application icon, but I doubt that's all you want to do, given how you phrased your question.